# Bitbucket pipelines add additional php extensions

Tags: php, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using the bitbucket pipelines and use the docker image from garak/docker-php7:7.1

Now I need the php-soap extension, which is not in the image above. How can I install it in runtime? Or is there a possibility to put the whole docker configuration in my pipelines config, whitout to pull it from github?

Comment: Is that your server is running using docker container ?

Comment: Well I haven't fix it in this way. I have read a bit and create my own docker container. So I can manage now the extensions on my self.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically like the explain here https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/php-with-bitbucket-pipelines-873907835.html

You have to use `docker-php-ext-install`, which is a function from the official docker image for PHP. Check out https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/315#issuecomment-264645332 ,  in this link you have all the dependencies to install soap extension.

`apt-get install -y libxml2-dev php-soap && apt-get clean -y && docker-php-ext-install soap`